# Using same operator with different parameters

Tags: c++, interface

I'm considering a "map of maps" type, and wonder if it would be considered bad practice to have two `operator[]`s, with different parameters having different meaning. Suppose the "outer" map is indexed by `OuterKeyType` and the inner maps by `InnerKeyType`, and we have an object of the "map of maps" `m`. Then the behaviour would be that `m[OuterKeyType]` would return (a reference to) the entire inner map indexed by that key, while `m[InnerKeyType]` would return a compound formed by some operation across all the maps on the element indexed (it can be assumed all the maps have the same set of keys).

So, is this design counterintuitive and bad, or is it just convenient and thus good?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you've effectively got a matrix of values with the InnerKey being the row index and the OuterKey being the column index (or vice-versa) and that you want to get the row or column of for a given index?

Comment: Well, yes, sort of. Hadn't thought about it like that before, acually

Comment: What's wrong with literally just a map of maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is that it is a really bad idea in general to hide different behaviors under the same function name just by the operands that are being passed. It makes it hard to determine what logic will be triggered when you encounter `obj[value]`, as it will have completely different behavior depending on what `value` is, which might or not be visible while reading this code.

I would recommend that you provide *named* functions for the operations, just because you can overload an operator it does not mean that you *should*. Depending on the domain the functions would have different names: `obj.getX(value)` and `obj.getY(value)` are much easier to understand provided that `X` and `Y` are sensible names.

Answer (score 0):

As this [tutorial](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.10) states, you should not overload the `operator []` but the `operator ()`. It is more safe, faster and C++ish than the C "array of array" operator.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/05/10/performant-isn-t-a-word.aspx. Also, I wouldn't say changing which operator I overload changes the underlying quality, safety or performance of my code.

Comment: @carlpet: sorry, I got mixed up with german. I even edited my post 4 hours ago, also, your link points nowhere. To your comment: The article I posted the link to explains in detail, why the "`operator[][]`" is not as fast/typesafe as a simple `operator()`. And it *does* make a difference, since the `operator[][]` is not supported in C++ and would have to be emulated with proxies or nested mapping types.

Comment: The link works for me, but was mostly aimed at @Mattheiu anyways. My point was that if I implement `operator()` the same way I'd implement `operator[]`, there would be no gain. The only _real_ difference I'd say is the ability of `operator()` to take several parameters. On the other hand, I'd say the indexing operator is quite establishes as how to get an element from a collection, whereas the function call operator could do just about anything.